# Javascript - Remove oldest elements of a map (object)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6

I have an object:

```
let lastPosts = {
  id1: {
    date: new Date("10/10/2000 11:30:34"),
  },
  id2: {
    date: new Date("10/10/2000 10:00:00"),
  },
  id3: {
    date: new Date("10/10/2000 10:01:30"),
  },
  id4: {
    date: new Date("11/10/2000 13:09:30"),
  },
  id5: {
    date: new Date("8/10/2005 18:10:15"),
  },
  id6: {
    date: new Date("11/10/2000 10:00:11"),
  },
  id7: {
    date: new Date("10/10/2000 10:00:01"),
  },
  id8: {
    date: new Date("15/10/2000 11:30:34"),
  },
  id9: {
    date: new Date("7/10/2002 11:30:34"),
  },
  id10: {
    date: new Date("8/10/2005 18:10:14"),
  },
  id11: {
    date: new Date("11/10/2000 10:00:00"),
  },
};
```

and I need to ensure that "lastPosts" only contains 9 posts (elements), deleting the remaining oldest posts.

```
function deleteOldestLastPosts(lastPosts) {
    if (Object.keys(lastPosts).length > 9) {
       // What can I do here?
    }
}
```

So, that I have the following result:

```
{
  id1: {
    date: new Date("10/10/2000 11:30:34"),
  },
  id3: {
    date: new Date("10/10/2000 10:01:30"),
  },
  id4: {
    date: new Date("11/10/2000 13:09:30"),
  },
  id5: {
    date: new Date("8/10/2005 18:10:15"),
  },
  id6: {
    date: new Date("11/10/2000 10:00:11"),
  },
  id8: {
    date: new Date("15/10/2000 11:30:34"),
  },
  id9: {
    date: new Date("7/10/2002 11:30:34"),
  },
  id10: {
    date: new Date("8/10/2005 18:10:14"),
  },
  id11: {
    date: new Date("11/10/2000 10:00:00"),
  },
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Sort `Object.values(lastPosts)` by date. Then find the property with the first date and delete it.

Comment: How big `lastPosts` could be? Do you care about optimisation and efficiency in finding k largest items?

Comment: @HosseinDehnokhalaji Its max size should be 10, but might be little bigger (not really big, something small)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort all the values by date. Remove the newest 9 elements from this sorted array, producing an array of the dates to delete. Then loop through the properties, removing it if it's in the array.

```js
function deleteOldestLastPosts(lastPosts) {
  let values = Object.values(lastPosts);
  if (values.length > 9) {
    let datesToDelete = values.map(el => el.date).sort((a, b) => a - b);
    datesToDelete.splice(-9);
    Object.entries(lastPosts).forEach(([key, {
      date
    }]) => {
      if (datesToDelete.includes(date)) {
        delete lastPosts[key];
      }
    });
  }
}

let lastPosts = {
  id1: {
    date: new Date("10/10/2000 11:30:34"),
  },
  id2: {
    date: new Date("10/10/2000 10:00:00"),
  },
  id3: {
    date: new Date("10/10/2000 10:01:30"),
  },
  id4: {
    date: new Date("11/10/2000 13:09:30"),
  },
  id5: {
    date: new Date("8/10/2005 18:10:15"),
  },
  id6: {
    date: new Date("11/10/2000 10:00:11"),
  },
  id7: {
    date: new Date("10/10/2000 10:00:01"),
  },
  id8: {
    date: new Date("15/10/2000 11:30:34"),
  },
  id9: {
    date: new Date("7/10/2002 11:30:34"),
  },
  id10: {
    date: new Date("8/10/2005 18:10:14"),
  },
  id11: {
    date: new Date("11/10/2000 10:00:00"),
  },
};

deleteOldestLastPosts(lastPosts);
console.log(lastPosts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a priority queue. Javascript does not have one in-built, but you can find a package that provides it, or write one from scratch.

Use a min priority queue to store the `id_n` objects, using `date` field as the criteria. As soon as size of queue becomes > 9, remove the element at top of priority queue. Then, take that removed element's `id_n` and remove it from the current object (`lastPosts`).

At the end, you will have latest 9 elements in priority queue. And your object (`lastPosts`) will have latest 9 `id_n` objects.

The time complexity will be `O(n log k)`, `n` is size of `lastPosts` and k is `9`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function `getlastPosts` that will:

- sort the json object by date descending
- return the first `n` elements of the json object using `filter` by the index of entries

The function uses [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on the array [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the JSON object.

```js
let lastPosts = {
  id1: {
    date: new Date("10/10/2000 11:30:34"),
  },
  id2: {
    date: new Date("10/10/2000 10:00:00"),
  },
  id3: {
    date: new Date("10/10/2000 10:01:30"),
  },
  id4: {
    date: new Date("11/10/2000 13:09:30"),
  },
  id5: {
    date: new Date("8/10/2005 18:10:15"),
  },
  id6: {
    date: new Date("11/10/2000 10:00:11"),
  },
  id7: {
    date: new Date("10/10/2000 10:00:01"),
  },
  id8: {
    date: new Date("15/10/2000 11:30:34"),
  },
  id9: {
    date: new Date("7/10/2002 11:30:34"),
  },
  id10: {
    date: new Date("8/10/2005 18:10:14"),
  },
  id11: {
    date: new Date("11/10/2000 10:00:00"),
  },
};

function getlastPosts(posts, n) {
  return Object.entries(posts)
    .sort(([, a], [, b]) => b.date - a.date)
    .filter((e, i) => i < n)
    .reduce((r, [k, v]) => ({ ...r, [k]: v }), {})
}

// get first 3 elements
console.log(getlastPosts(lastPosts, 3));
```

See also [Sorting object property by values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069840/2314737)